# Access package assignment approval update via MSGraph API returns HTTP 403: Only user tokens are supported

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to call [Access package assignment approval update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/approvalstep-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) via MSGraph Beta API (Java 0.51.0-SNAPSHOT). The call fails with following error:

```
2022-08-26 22:32:44.239 ERROR 10208 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] global                                   : CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 408Graph service exception
2022-08-26 22:32:44.239 ERROR 10208 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] global                                   : Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: 
Error message: Only user tokens are supported

PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityGovernance/entitlementManagement/accessPackageAssignmentApprovals/aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa/steps/bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb
SdkVersion : graph-java/v0.51.0
[...]

403 : Forbidden
[...]

[Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
```

Based on the error message can I think, that Application tokens are not really supported, but the strange thing is, that I can call [Access package assignment approval get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/approval-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) without any issue. I have of course delegated the permission *EntitlementManagement.ReadWrite.All* to the Application user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment using [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and got the below results:***

I am able to retrieve the properties of an approval object successfully like this:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityGovernance/entitlementManagement/accessPackageAssignmentApprovals/<id>
```

**Response:**

[image]

***To update those properties, I ran the same query as you like below, and it got updated successfully:***

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityGovernance/entitlementManagement/accessPackageAssignmentApprovals/<id>/steps/<id>
{
"reviewResult": "Approve",
"justification": "Please approve"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

***Make sure to pass 'Request body' with the `PATCH` query. Please check whether you are giving correct id's or not in the query.***

> The `<id>` before **/steps/** in the query is the **`id`** of *accessPackageAssignmentRequest* that is in **`PendingApproval`** State.

To get that **`id`**, you can run the below query:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityGovernance/entitlementManagement/accessPackageAssignmentRequests?$expand=requestor($expand=connectedOrganization)&$filter=(requestState eq 'PendingApproval')
```

**Response:**

[image]

The `<id>` after **/steps/** in the query is the **`step id`** that I got by running below query:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityGovernance/entitlementManagement/accessPackageAssignmentApprovals/<id_that_you _got_in_above_query>
```

**Response:**

[image]

**UPDATE**

Please **note** that, you cannot update Access package assignment approval using **`Application`** permissions. Application permissions are not supported for **PATCH** query.

You can refer this **[MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/approvalstep-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions)** to confirm that like below:

[image]

So, it will only work if you login with **work or school account**(personal-login)

Comment: Hi @Shridevi M, Can you share which type of auth-token you use in graph explorer?

For me my-personal login was already working, this error is ONLY when my java-deamon-app calls the same API using access-token-with-application-permission

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-call-api?tabs=java)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I logged in with my account. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: First, thank you for the great answer! Yeah, now I found the way how to get personal oauth2 token, API works with it seamlessly. Strange that GET requests for this API don’t allow Application token as well, at least based on the documentation. For me they worked previously (even POST request for cancel on the access package request works with Application token).